# Load Data from Database in populate DropDownList in mvc Razors

Tags: html

I am new in mvc razors.I have a problem of doing load data from database in populate dropdownlist in mvc razors.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add your database items to a List in your ViewModel, then pass it to your view and have razor render it.

**Here's a very simple example:**

**View:**

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.DropDownList("DesiredDropDownListName", new SelectList(Model.MyList))
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
```

**Controller Action:**

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
var list = LoadList();
vm.MyList = list;
return View("Index", vm);


//Example list - load database items here and add to list
public List<string> LoadList()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Apple");
    list.Add("Orange");
    list.Add("Strawberry");
    list.Add("etc..");
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Kindly post code of load data from sql server database to cascanding dropdownlist in mvc razors.